# How to append quantity of right/wrong answers in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to ask your help. I right code of the geographical quiz. In this quiz there is a table with quantity of right/wrong answers. There are some stamps of countries and you should guess what stamps suit to which envelope. 
There is a table:

```
<table class = "table table-responsive countries-scores">
    <tr>
        <td>Name of the country</td>
        <td>Quantity of stamps</td>
        <td>Quantity of right answers</td>
        <td>Quantity of wrong answers</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

And there is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $.each( countries, function( key, value ) {
        var tr = '<tr><td>';
        tr+=key;
        tr += '</td><td>';
        tr += value.stamps.length;
        tr += '</td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
        $(".countries-scores").append(tr);
    });
 });
```

It's repository of answers:

```
var countries = {
    brazil: {
        id: "BrazCanvas",
        color: 'red',
        title: 'from Brazil',
        stamps: ['brazilian1', 'brazilian2', 'brazilian3', 'brazilian4', 'brazilian5', 'brazilian6'],
    },
    india: {
        id: 'IndCanvas',
        color: 'green',
        title: "From India",
        stamps: ['india1', 'india2', 'india3', 'india4'],
    },
    china: {
        id: "ChiCanvas",
        color: "yellow",
        title: "From China",
        stamps: ['china1', 'china2', 'china3', 'china4'],
    },
    africa: {
        id: "AfrCanvas",
        color: "blue",
        title: "From South Africa",
        stamps: ['africa1', 'africa2', 'africa3', 'africa4'],
    },
    russia: {
        id: "RusCanvas",
        color: "brown",
        title: "From Russia",
        stamps: ['russia1', 'russia3'],
    },
}


var postSpamps = {
    brazilian1:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil1.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil1',
        alt: 'Brazilian Bird',
    },
    india1:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/india1.jpg',
        class1: 'ind-drop',
        id: 'India1',
        alt: 'India1',
    },
    russia1:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/russia1.jpg',
        class1: 'rus-drop',
        id: 'Russia1',
        alt: 'Russia1',
    },
    africa1:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/africa1.jpg',
        class1: 'afr-drop',
        id: 'Africa1',
        alt: 'Africa1',
    },
    china1:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/china1.jpg',
        class1: 'chin-drop',
        id: 'China1',
        alt: 'China1',
    },
    brazilian2:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil2.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil2',
        alt: 'Brazil2',
    },
    brazilian3:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil3.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil3',
        alt: 'brazil3',
    },
    india2:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/india2.jpg',
        class1: 'ind-drop',
        id: 'India2',
        alt: 'India2',
    },
    africa2:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/africa2.jpg',
        class1: 'afr-drop',
        id: 'Africa2',
        alt: 'Africa2',
    },
    china2:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/china2.jpg',
        class1: 'chin-drop',
        id: 'China2',
        alt: 'China2',
    },
    brazilian4:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil4.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil4',
        alt: 'Brazilian Bird',
    },
    india3:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/india3.jpg',
        class1: 'ind-drop',
        id: 'India3',
        alt: 'India3',
    },
    russia3:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/russia2.jpg',
        class1: 'rus-drop',
        id: 'Russia2',
        alt: 'Russia2',
    },
    africa3:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/africa3.jpg',
        class1: 'afr-drop',
        id: 'Africa3',
        alt: 'Africa3',
    },
    china3:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/china3.jpg',
        class1: 'chin-drop',
        id: 'China3',
        alt: 'China3',
    },
    brazilian5:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil5.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil5',
        alt: 'Brazilian5',
    },
    brazilian6:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/brazil6.jpg',
        class1: 'braz-drop',
        id: 'brazil6',
        alt: 'brazil6',
    },
    india4:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/india4.jpg',
        class1: 'ind-drop',
        id: 'India4',
        alt: 'India4',
    },
    africa4:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/africa4.jpg',
        class1: 'afr-drop',
        id: 'Africa4',
        alt: 'Africa4',
    },
    china4:  {
        src: 'img/postcards/china4.jpg',
        class1: 'chin-drop',
        id: 'China4',
        alt: 'China4',
    },
}
```

My goal is to add right and wrong answers in this table. If user answers good quantity of right answer should increase. If he answers bad quantity of wrong answers should increase also.
What should I do?
Thank you for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: Show us your `countries` json, so that it will clear how your answers are stored.

Comment: @RohanKumar but if they do that, we'll know the answers!

Comment: @George why not I just want to see your imaginations. :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the quiz form look like or how right or wrong was handled. But perhaps I can give pointers as such.

Update your html to include `class country name` and column `right` and `wrong`.

```
  $.each(countries, function(key, value) {
    var tr = '<tr class="' + key + '"><td>';
    tr += key;
    tr += '</td><td>';
    tr += value.stamps.length;
    tr += '</td> <td class="right"></td> <td class="wrong"></td> </tr>';
    $(".countries-scores").append(tr);
  });
```

Then you can update right and wrong as such.

```
  // brazil 4
  $(".brazil .wrong").html("4");

  // china 5
  $(".china .wrong").html("5");

  // or wrap into a function call
  updateRight("brazil", 10);


function updateRight(countryName, quantity) {
  $("." + countryName).find(".right").html(quantity);
}
```